# Noun Project CSS wrapper?

Tags: css

I can't find the link anywhere, and I searched all over Hacker News (where I recall seeing the project), with no luck.

Instead of having to download the images from The Noun Project and such, you just included a css file and specified the name of the noun as a class under the  tag, or something.  Is this out there?!

Comment: i've had a good look as well and it doesn't seem that you can with this one. Have you seen Chris Coyier's article on flat icons? http://css-tricks.com/flat-icons-icon-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of the Font Awesome, the pictographic font with 150 icons, that can be used with twitter bootstrap.

With Fort Awesome, you link to FontAwesome in a CSS tag. Then you add the class of the icon you want to an HTML element.

In my [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xPGMK/), I have a camera and play circle beside some text.

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean: http://nounpack.com ?
They have a sprite with many icons taken from the noun project and then you can include them as icons with css.

Comment: The site is no longer active. im searching for alternatives any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Nick Silva that [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) is undoubtedly the best place to start for effortless 'noun project-esque' css.

That said, to answer your question, to use Noun Project icons directly you would need to wrap your own. The best way to do this (IMHO) is to use [Font Custom](http://fontcustom.com/)

Font Custom is a command line tool used to generate custom icon webfonts (CSS) from SVGs (Noun Project icons)